# Pallellelized DFS : Would task explosion break this program for large graphs?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

In the following DFS implementation, a task would be created for each edge in the given graph. A given task would complete only after all the child tasks it spawns have completed. Would this cause any scale problems for large graphs? 
How do I deal with it?

```
//destination node -> source node ie., for each node, identifies the node which led ot the given node
ConcurrentDictionary<Node, Node> path = new ConcurrentDictionary<Node, Node>();

bool ParallelDFS(Node src, Node dest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if(src == dest)
    {
        cancellationToken.Cancel();
        return true;
    }

    //dest maps to src only the first time dest is encountered during traversal
    bool firstvisit = path.TryAdd(dest,src);

    if(!firstvisit)
        return false;

    return dest.neighbors.AsParallel().Any( (node) => ParallelDFS(node, dest, cancellationToken) );


}
```

What other potential problems do you see with this implementation of DFS algorithm?

Comment: I would think it would be inefficient to create a new thread for every neighbour. This must add a lot of overhead. How does performance compare to non-parallel?

Comment: @MartinCapodici yet to test it..note : it is task...need not necessarily translate to a thread.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a depth-first search to me.  It looks like it's breadth-first.

Comment: @Aadith ok fair enough. Deciding whether or not to create a thread could be a lot more overhead than the dictionary look up (which is all you need to do in non-parallel). I feel it needs to go parallel less often. Maybe at every N depth?

Comment: @Rob its hard to argue on that...at the node that is immediately adjacent to the destination, it would behave like BFS...but in other cases, it is just parallelizes DFS traversal

Comment: @MartinCapodici I agree with and like the last statement in your comment..as for the rest, I am not sure...a non-parallel implementation would iteratively recurse through each neighbor...as to whether thats cost effective would really depend on the structure of the graph

Comment: @Aadith Yes, you're absolutely right - it is DFS - sorry.

Comment: Assuming you mean on windows: The TPL libraries are using the C# thread pool, which uses the windows thread pool. It won't cause too many threads or stacks... What can happen is a simple out-of-memory problem. This would require an outrageous number of tasks. If an excessive number of tasks became I/O bound, you might run into problems with too many, but windows thread pool usually avoids that, by itself.

Answer (score 0):

> In the following DFS implementation, a task would be created for each edge in the given graph.

No, it won't. The parallel algorithms in TPL in general try to be efficient and not create more `Task`s than necessary. The approach PLINQ takes is to create one `Task` per CPU core for each PLINQ query. But still going to be a lot and since you're doing only a very small amount of work per iteration, it's very likely going to mean that the overhead of parallelization is going to outweigh any gains.

I believe a better approach would be a variant of the producer-consumer pattern: Have a small number of tasks that process a queue of node pairs. And when a task encounters a node that wasn't visited yet, add its neighbors to the queue.

Managing those `Task`s manually should be relatively simple. Another approach would be to use a `BlockingCollection<T>` for the queue and  `Parallel.ForEach()` with [`GetConsumingPartitioner()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) to process it.